# Windows 10 Start Button Repeatedly Becomes Non-Responsive

Tags: windows-10

I found a fix for reinstalling the Start Button and all its features when it becomes non-responsive i.e. nothing happens when pushed on the keyboard or clicked on.

https://www.techmesto.com/fix-start-menu-broken-windows-10-technical-preview/

However, this non-response has recurred many times so I have had to apply the above fix multiple times as well i.e. the fix seems to be only temporary. Does anyone know what in my system might be causing this to happen?